# javascript : how to distinguish between selected element list and form

Tags: javascript

Here is the scripts: http://jsbin.com/itusut/6/edit

Hi, i have function:

```
function on(t, e, f) {
    if ( e.length ) {
        var l = e.length,
        n = 0;

        for ( ; n < l; n++ ) {
            e[n].addEventListener(t, f, false)
        }
    } else {
        e.addEventListener(t, f, false);
    }
}
```

if we do `var handle = document.getElementsByClassName('some-class');` then `handle` is a node list.

if we do `var handle = document.getElementById('an-id');` then `handle` is a single node.

The problem is, when i choose `<form id="login-form">` it returns **array** not single element.

So, my `on` function is fail. The function use `elm.length` filter. Everything is ok, except for `<form>` . How to fix this? i know **elm.length** not work properly on single node `<form>` element.

Would you help? Thank you very much

Comment: You could add a check for tag name but @zzzzBov 's answer seems a bit more appropriate.

Comment: `if (e.length && !e.nodeName) {`

Comment: @crazy-train : e.nodeName is the accurate answer, why not making an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Form elements have a length property (to tell the number of fields in the form). The code you're using doesn't accurately detect whether the element is a DOM node, so it assumes that the form is a collection of DOM nodes.

If you need to bind elements, you're probably better off always passing in an array or array-like object, so that the function always iterates over the collection.

This could be as simple as wrapping the parameter in an array:

```
on('click', [formElement], callback);
```

---

<sub>Updated version of `on` where only lists are supported:</sub>

```
function on(type, elements, callback) {
    var length,
        i;
    length = 0;
    if (elements && elements.length) {
        length = elements.length;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < length; i += 1) {
        elements[i].addEventListener(type, callback, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: what should i write instead of `e.length` :( thank you for answering

Comment: You don't need to. Just require that the caller always pass in an array or NodeList.

Comment: @zzzzBov : yes, i think it is better to pass them in array/ array-like object. i would try this `always for ()` instead of `if else`

Comment: @zzzzBov : great... i've tried your updated scripts. But it still depend on `elements.length` which means, it is still fail on single selected `<form>` element

Comment: @SlametBedjo, I explicitly said "only lists are supported", which means you should wrap single elements in an array.

Comment: @zzzzBov : Thank you very much ! Yes, it is better to use your method (wrap single element and loop it)